# Moose::Role weirdness with overridden methods

Tags: oop, overriding, moose, perl

`Base.pm`:

```
package Base;
use Moose::Role;

sub f {
  my ($self) = @_;
  print "In role.\n";
}

1;
```

`X.pm`:

```
package X;
use Moose;

with 'Base';

around 'f' => sub {
  my ($next, $self) = @_;
  print "Nevermind, we are in class X.\n";
};

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
1;
```

`Y.pm`:

```
package Y;
use Moose;

with 'Base';

override 'f' => sub {
  my ($self) = @_;
  print "Nevermind, we are in class Y.\n";
};

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
1;
```

Then X does work and Y does not. It is a weird design, as `override` is just a special case of `around` and as a special case should work also.

Can anyone explain why this design decision and why it is so weird?

```
$ perl X.pm 
$ perl Y.pm 
Cannot add an override method if a local method is already present at /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22/Moose/Exporter.pm line 419
    Moose::override('f', 'CODE(0x9c002f8)') called at Y.pm line 9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation describes *`override`*](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose#override-($name,-&sub)) as:

> An override method is a way of explicitly saying "I am overriding this method from my superclass". You can call `super` within this method, and it will work as expected. The same thing can be accomplished with a normal method call and the `SUPER::` pseudo-package; it is really your choice.

What you are doing contradicts this definition. With a role, `f` is installed in your package. You are attempting to define another `f` in the same package.

The fact that your role is called `Base` indicates to me that you have some confusion when it comes to the difference between inheritance versus composition.

The [purpose of `around`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/MethodModifiers.pod) is to wrap a method in the current class regardless of whether it was implemented in the same package or inherited or composed:

> Method modifiers can be used to add behavior to methods without modifying the definition of those methods.

Just a straightforward reading of these two snippets makes the distinction clear to me.

When you apply the role that defines `f`, that itself overrides any inherited method `f`. If you then say `override 'f'`, you are declaring your intention to override `f` again. Well, there can only be one method `f` in one class. Which one should count? The one that you get by applying the role, or the one you just defined? For all intents and purposes, the methods you get from composing a role are just like methods you defined manually in the class. There is no reason `a priori` one should be more important than the other.

Think of this as airline travel. Think of the method modifiers as classes: First, business, economy etc. So, in first class, `get_dinner_menu` maybe wrapped with appetizers, sweets, desserts etc.

On the other hand, `override` is like changing the flight. It's as if you are saying "I want to fly on both TK 1 and UIA 213". Makes no sense.

Maybe the following script will make things a bit clearer by showing a naive implementation of `around` and overriding a method without using `override`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

{
    package MyRole;

    use Moose::Role;

    sub f {
        print "in role\n";
    }
}

{
    package X;
    use Moose;

    with 'MyRole';

    around 'f' => sub {
        my ($orig, $self) = @_;
        print "In wrapper\n";
        return $self->$orig( @_ );
    };

    {
        my $f = \&f;
        {
            no warnings 'redefine';
            *f = sub {
                my ($self) = @_;
                print "In wrapper wrapper\n";
                return $self->$f( @_ );
            }
        }
    }
}

{
    package Y;

    use Moose;
    with 'MyRole';

    sub f {
        print "In overridden method\n";
    }
}

print '=-=' x 22, "\n";

my $x = X->new;
$x->f;

print '=-=' x 22, "\n";

my $y = Y->new;
$y->f;
```

Output:

```
=-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-= 
In wrapper wrapper                                                 
In wrapper                                                         
in role                                                            
=-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-= 
In overridden method
```

Comment: But why on the Earth, `around` in this case **does** work? Can't the same be said about `around` to justify that it should not work?

Comment: Got it. But allowing *both* `sub` and `around` for the same method in one class looks like a design error for me

Comment: There is nothing to be gained by ***prohibiting*** `sub f` and `around 'f'` in the same package, because composing a role that provides `f` installs `f` as a sub in the package. So, that prohibition makes using `around` with composed methods either impossible or difficult. I haven't thought too much about it.